# Updating a Kafka Image and adding a snowflakes connector

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please how does one go about updating and adding a snowflake connector to an existing kafka image?

curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/snowflake/snowflake-kafka-connector/1.9.1/snowflake-kafka-connector-1.9.1.jar --output snowflake-kafka-connector-1.9.1.jar

I have tried adding the above code to the docker file using RUN but nothing seems to be working